# How to Authorize Asp.Net Web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

First I'm going to give some brief explanation where i'm trying to explain where I am at this moment:
I've gotten to a point where I'm about to give this up but I figured I'd give stackoverflow a shot first. I have created a web api from an empty template and included the web api reference. I then added a web api 2 controller with actions, using Entity Framework, to create get,post,delete, put methods to my Codefirst from database. This was quite easy to accomplish even for me as an absolute beginner in this and programming overall for that matter. I then looked into authorization and learned that i can add [Authorization] attribute to my controllers so that there is a need of some kind of authentication. So far this all works but now things gets alot more complicated and the examples i manage to find are extremely long and hard to follow. My question is as follows:

Once I've added authorization attribute to the controllers which results in a 401 Unauthorized if called, how do i let people that are stored in my sql database acess theese attributes thru http calls with Ajax from my app?

Hopefully you understand where I'm at and where I'm trying to get to, any help at all is highly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: you will need to implement an authentication filter. See following link for overview http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters. And this link is some sample code http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/BasicAuthentication/ReadMe.txt

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the flowing tutorials:

[Secure a Web API with Individual Accounts and Local Login in ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)